# Ckeditor appears only in first field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I have partial with `ckeditor` field in it.

```
<%= form_for [point, page], role: 'form' do |f| %>

    ...

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :article, 'Текст' %>
      <%= f.cktext_area :article, class: 'form-control', rows: 10, ckeditor: {toolbar: 'mini'} %>
    </div>

    ...

<% end %>
```

I have two such forms on a page, generated with this code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <%= render partial: 'point_pages/index_page', locals: {point: @point, page: @page_from} %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <%= render partial: 'point_pages/index_page', locals: {point: @point, page: @page_to} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

but ckeditor loads only on first form. On second partial (with `@page_to`) it loads only text area without ckeditor toolbar.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with duplicating `id`s of a text field.

Ckeditor attach it's toolbar to field with certain `id`. And as I have 2 similar `id`s on one page, because of 2 similar partials, it attach toolbar only to first one.

Hope, this answer will help somebody someday :)